# Is it safe to use ServletContext#getMimeType()

Tags: servlets, mime-types

To be more specific I am using:

```
public String getMimeType() {
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    String filePath = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length()+1, request.getRequestURI().length());
    String fileName = context.getRealPath(filePath);        
    return context.getMimeType(fileName);
}
```

To determine the type of file being requested from the client (css, js, font etc). Different actions occur depending on the type of file. Is this consistent across browsers or generally a safe way to determine a file type based on the filename passed in the url or does it break too easily?

Comment: It is based on the file extension, not the file content, so it way be inaccurate, since different file format may share the same extension.

Comment: In other words for file uploading its a no-go, but for internal app (requesting my own resources) it should be fine? I have been noticing a lot of random 404's on resource calls and haven't been able to pin point if this is the culprit. So there is no way request.getMimeType could be returning nulls based on something the browser is doing?

Comment: You are switch around now. You code is `context.getMimeType()`, but now you're talking about `request.getMimeType()`. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry context...typo.

Comment: If you're using Tomcat, the `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` file contains all the default mappings of file extension to mime-type, as returned by `context.getMimeType`. Any mappings in your own `WEB-INF/web.xml` file extends those defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this consistent across browsers?*

The mime type associated with the file extension is in this particular code snippet not determined by client. It is determined by server based on `<mime-mapping>` entries in `web.xml`. All which the client has control over is the file extension in the URL. But you already know that.

So, you'd better ask instead *"Is this concistent across servers?"*. The answer to that is *No*. Each server has its own predefined mime mappings. Older servers may lack mappings for newer mime types such as XLSX, SVG, etc. If you'd like to cover every mime type of your interest, and you don't have control over the target server and its configuration, then you'd better explicitly map it in webapp's own `web.xml`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please skip that `getRealPath()` nonsense. It's never needed in a decent web application. Moreover, you don't technically need it here at all. An URI or even the sole filename works as good for `getMimeType()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the added unrelated.